# Каким образом можно наполнить android.graphics.Path массивом из координат?

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, path

У меня есть класс Path, который рисуется на canvas. Как можно наполнить его массивом из координат? ( x,y ).

Я пытался сделать вот так:

```
public class SurfaceHelperGame extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

String arr;
String[] ss;

DrawThread drawThread;
public SurfaceHelperGame(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context,attributeSet);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    arr = "263,427,297,409,331,397,369,395,426,419,483,463,524,511,560,563,584,627,599,693,606,772,601,847," +
            "589,919,568,967,539,1004,505,1018,473,1023,418,1019,347,992,277,947,217,877,17" +
            "9,799,158,698,155,578,173,455,203,356,239,280,277,252,314,258,371,316,434,436," +
            "475,563,485,649,485,649"; // Нечетный элемент - x, четный - y
    ss = arr.split(",");

    drawThread = new DrawThread(getContext(),getHolder());
    drawThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // РёР·РјРµРЅРµРЅРёРµ СЂР°Р·РјРµСЂРѕРІ SurfaceView
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    drawThread.requestStop();
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            drawThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {/* ... */}
    }
}

public void myDrawPath() {
    for (int i = 1; i <ss.length-1 ; i += 2) {
        drawThread.path.moveTo(Float.valueOf(ss[i]),Float.valueOf(ss[i+1]));
        drawThread.path.lineTo(Float.valueOf(ss[i]),Float.valueOf(ss[i+1]));
    }
}

public class DrawThread extends Thread {

    Path path = new Path();
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    volatile boolean running = true;//С„Р»Р°Рі РґР»СЏ РѕСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєРё РїРѕС‚РѕРєР°


    public DrawThread(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        myDrawPath();
    }

    public void requestStop() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            if (canvas != null) {
                try {
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                } finally {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

В методе myDrawPath пытался с помощью Path вывести на канвас точки, но так по-прежнему пусто

Comment: у данного класса множество методов, вам необходимо уточнить вопрос. Например я буду использовать только lineTo, у самого класса нет возможности принять array координат, ибо ему нужно знать с какой начать, где остановиться, где рисовать, какой алгоритм использовать, те логика.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei , дополнил вопрос

Comment: ну вот видите, то что я сразу и предположил, для начала из цикла moveTo уберите. И вы так и не уточнили вопрос

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei , не понимаю, что нужно уточнить. У меня есть массив координат ( правда склеенный в один ), циклом мне нужно нарисовать Path из этого полного массива. Я и не думал передавать сразу массив координат

Comment: ну прочтите первый комментарий, вас будет устраивать то что у вас Path будет риосвать всегда by LineTO ? какая у вас логика отрисовки. В вашем вопросе нет проблемы, кроме как понимания как это работает, вы можете написать свою функцию для того чтоб рисовать Path по Array как у вас, просто нужно знать какую, логику использовать для этого вот и всё. Опять же см 1 коммент

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei , спасибо, я решил проблему

Comment: позже можете описать ваше решение в ответ, для того чтобы закрыть вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы:

```
public void myDrawPath() {
    drawThread.path.moveTo(Float.valueOf(ss[1]),Float.valueOf(ss[2]));
    drawThread.path.lineTo(Float.valueOf(ss[3]), Float.valueOf(ss[4]));
    for (int i = 5; i <ss.length-2 ; i += 2) {
        if(Math.abs(Float.valueOf(ss[i]) - Float.valueOf(ss[i-2])) > 100 || Math.abs(Float.valueOf(ss[i+1]) - Float.valueOf(ss[i-1])) > 100)
            drawThread.path.moveTo(Float.valueOf(ss[i]), Float.valueOf(ss[i+1]));
        drawThread.path.lineTo(Float.valueOf(ss[i]),Float.valueOf(ss[i+1]));
    }
}
```